# Javascript - Unintentional firing of event in parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, mouseleave

Here is a problem I have been facing for a long time now. I've tried everything I know but somehow it still eludes me.

I have an APEX application where I have created a table using DIV elements (I was using a HTML table before and the issue is also present there).
This is the structure of my table.
[image: HTML structure]

I have to include mouse interactions on this table and thus I have bound (using jquery delegate function) the **mouseenter**, **mousemove** and **mouseleave** events in all the cell divs. Also there is a **mouseleave** event on the main table div which closes a popup that shows up on **mouseenter** in any of the cell divs. So to summarize the event handlers:

Cell divs:
**mouseenter** : shows a popup div and highlights the cell
**mousemove** : animates the popup div to move to the new mouse pointer location
**mouseleave** : removes the highlight on the cell. No need to hide the popup div now as it'll be shown again by the next cell where the mouse moves to

Main table div:
**mouseleave** : to finally hide the popup div as the mouse pointer is now out of the table area

Problem:

*Sometimes* when moving the mouse *within the table area* to the right or down as indicated by the arrows in the diagram, the **mouseleave** event handler of the main table div fires. When I check the target property of this event it shows that the event was fired by one of the cell divs. But I have included the stopPropagation call in the mouseleave handler of the cell divs. This behavior is not seen when the mouse pointer is moved left or top. (unable to understand why. The mouseleave of the cell div fires but its not propagated up)

Also most of the time the mouseleave event of the main table div does not fire and thus the popup does not hide. This is the main issue.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. 
I'm unable to post the code on jsfiddle because it'll take me a lot of work just to set it up on the fiddle. However I will do it if requested.

**EDIT**: Here is a simplified setup on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arijitkanrar/mrpvy1bk/).

Here is the JS code as stackoverflow requests if inserting links to jsFiddle

```
    // cell div event handlers
$('#mainTable').delegate('div.bit','mouseenter', function(e){
    // highlight the cell
    $(this).addClass('highlight');

  // show the details popup near the cell
    $('#detailsPopup').css({
        "left": e.pageX + 10,
        "top": e.pageY + 10,
        "position": "absolute"
    }).show();
});

$('#mainTable').delegate('div.bit','mousemove', function(e){
    // move the details popup
    $('#detailsPopup').animate({
            "top": e.pageY + 10,
            "left": e.pageX + 10
        }, {
            "duration": 15,
            "queue": false
        });
});

$('#mainTable').delegate('div.bit','mouseleave', function(e){
    // remove the highlight from the cell
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});

$('#mainTable').mouseleave(function(e){
    // mouse has left the table area. hide the details popup
    $('#detailsPopup').hide();
});
```

However on the fiddle the code is working exactly as it should.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can u show your code?

Comment: If you add the code you used, or even better, a simplified example, it'd be a lot easier to figure out what is going on. An example is worth a lot more than a gigantic paragraph

Comment: Need the code, but you could try using .preventDefault() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on your mouseleave listeners.

Comment: Added jsFiddle link. Though there it works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `mouseout` instead of `mouseleave`? [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) you can read more about difference between these events.